# Vaadin or ZK for web and responsive web application

Tags: vaadin

I'm planning to develop an java web application. I am not sure which one would be the right fit for responsive

Vaadin or ZK ? or any other framework which is default by responsive.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The newest Vaadin 10 platform fits criteria of being responsive.

https://vaadin.com/blog/10-reasons-to-use-vaadin-10

- All the components are mobile friendly
- There are enablers for responsiveness and progressive web applications

Go to https://vaadin.com/start/v10-full-stack-spring to download full application for evaluation

Both Vaadin and ZK have similar open core business model, which means that core offering is free and open source, and some advanced components, features and services are commercial. Which one has better free offering is matter of taste. In Vaadin, the Grid component does not have limitations in free edition.

The open source license used by ZK is LGPL and Vaadin uses Apache 2.0 license. The latter one is more business friendly, since there is no copyleft.

The both have html based client side stack. ZK uses jQuery and Vaadin is based on web components. In both cases integrating custom html designs / templates is easy. Vaadin has Designer tool in commercial offering that produces html templates.

Comment: How about the performance in general when compared to zk?

Comment: Can you please help me with an example of Spring Boot + Vaadin 10 to kick start the project?

Comment: Go to https://vaadin.com/start/v10-full-stack-spring to download full application for evaluation.

Comment: I'ts fully open source of all the components like charts etc., like zk i saw pricing is referred in https://vaadin.com/pricing. please confirm what are the features is available for free for development. is there any restriction to develop commercial softwares without paying any free

Comment: I also come across the following http://forum.zkoss.org/question/89429/vaadin-vs-zk/  please kindly review and suggest

Comment: Thanks for the link. That is a bit old, and comparison is between older Vaadin version and ZK, so not applicable with Vaadin 10.

Comment: ZK pricing model is very similar to Vaadin, see it here: https://www.zkoss.org/price/pricing In both cases the idea is the same, there is core free offering, and commercial tools and services on top of that.

Comment: so which one is the best for responsive web app as per your experience

Comment: I can't say much about ZK, since I have not build complete apps with it. I have successfully implemented responsive UI's with Vaadin frameworks since version 7.

Comment: Furthermore, searching ZK gives 4K hits here at StackOverflow while searching Vaadin gives 11K hits. This is one indication that Vaadin seems to be more widely used.